# Activating leanModal dialog box with .click()

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to open a div with leanModal without having to click on a hyper link.
The link:

```
<a id="showform" rel="leanModal" name="signup" href="#trigger_id" style="display:none"></a>
```

the call to open the link:

```
<script>
var h = jQuery.noConflict();
h("#showform").click();
</script>
```

The initializing function:

```
var k = jQuery.noConflict();
k(function() {
    k('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({
        top: 50,
        overlay: 0.5,
        closeButton: ".modal_close"
    });
});​
```

If I use the hyper link it works but, I want this to open by itself.

Comment: Oh, this is not working!

Comment: Isn't that why you posted it?

Comment: Could it be because you are triggering click before the dom is loaded?

Answer (score 6):

Try it like this.  It seems you don't have the `("#showform").click();` inside a dom ready function.. which would fire the click before your leanModal are even initialized on you anchors and probably before your anchors exist in the dom..  Why don't you just trigger after you initialize

```
var k = jQuery.noConflict();
k(function() {
    k('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({
        top: 50,
        overlay: 0.5,
        closeButton: ".modal_close"
    });
    k("#showform").click();
});​
```

and remove the other script

Comment: Your Welcome :)  don't forget to click the green checkmark if it answered your question